# Variable 'cl' is passed by reference before it has been assigned a value for DataView Variable

Tags: vb.net

I have the following code passing a dataView variable to a function and I am getting the following warning:
“Variable ‘cl’ is passed by reference before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime.”

```
Function Editclass()
    Dim cl As DataView
    Bindclass (SqlConnection2, cl)
    Return cl
End Function


Sub Bindclass(ByVal conn As SqlConnection, ByRef cl As DataView)
    conn.Close()
    getdata.Connection = conn
    getdata.SQL = "SELECT * FROM POM_ClassView ORDER BY CLASSID"
    getdata.FillGridDropDown()
    cl = getdata.DataView
End Sub
```

How can I resolve the warning here please?

Comment: Just curious, why pass it in by reference rather than just making Bindclass a Function with a return type of DataView?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not really a concern based on your usage, but this will fix it.

```
Dim cl As DataView=nothing
```

Comment: Yes, that's what you must do to get rid of the warning, even though it doesn't change anything, since a variable is initialized to Nothing by default...